# Remove whitespaces and capitalize user input

Tags: java, replaceall, capitalize

I've made the code so it asks the user various questions, and if the `input.trim().isEmpty()` a message will be given to the user and will ask the user to input again. So if the user just writes blank spaces, message given. If the user gives a few blank spaces and some characters, it will accept.

Problem right now is that I want to capitalize the first letter of the Word, but it doesn't really work. Say if the user's input start with a letter then that will be capitalized. But if there's whitespace it wont capitalize at all.

So if input is:

> katka

Output is:

> katka

Another example:

> katka

Output is:

> Katka

Code is:

```
String askWork = input.nextLine();

String workplace = askWork.trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
 + askWork.substring(1);
```

while (askWork.trim().isEmpty()){
String askWork = input.nextLine();

```
String workplace = askWork.trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
 + askWork.substring(1);
```

}

I've tried different approaches but no success.

Comment: "if there's whitespace it wont capitalize at all."  What you want is the `trim()` method on `String`. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--)

Comment: You convert the first char to uppercase _and then_ you remove the whitespaces. Don't you think it would make _much more_ sense to remove the whitespaces first? Then you wouldn't (try) convert an whitespace to uppercase.

Comment: I agree. I tried askWork.trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + askWork.substring(1); But I am getting errors such as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutofBoundsException: String index out of range: 1 is given if the input is only whitespace. However, if the input contains characters it works excellent. I don't understand why..

Comment: @Ilja I updated my answer to handle this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`trim()` method on `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) will clear all leading and trailing whitespace.  The trimmed `String` must become your new `String` so that all indices you refer to after that are accurate. You will no longer need the `replaceAll("\\s","")`.  You also need logic to test for empty input.  You use the [`isEmpty()` method on `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) for that.  I've written a toy `main()` that keeps asking for a word and then capitalizes and prints it once it gets one.  It will test for blank input, input with no characters, etc.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String askWork = "";
        while (askWork.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Enter a word:");
            askWork = input.readLine().trim();
        }

        String workPlace = askWork.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + askWork.substring(1);

        System.out.println(workPlace);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your code and it worked great, if there was characters in it. If the input only had whitespace, I was given an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutofBoundsException: String index out of range: 1. Maybe there is something else that is wrong with my code? I will update my question.

Comment: Rewritten to address that issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because of whitespace as all the indices you refer while converting to uppercase are not accurate.
So first trim() the String so you can clear all leading and trailing whitespace and then capitalize it.
better check empty string and all whitespace to avoid exception.

```
String askWork = input.nextLine().trim();
String capitalized = askWork.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + askWork.substring(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try trimming your input to remove the whitespace, before attempting to capitalize it.

```
String askWork = input.nextLine().trim();
String capitalized = askWork.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + askWork.substring(1)
```

However, if the input is only whitespace, this will result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because after `trim()` is called `askWork` is set to the empty string (`""`) and you then try to access the first character of the empty (length 0) string.

```
String askWork = input.nextLine().trim();
if(askWork.isEmpty()) {
    // Display error
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bad!");
else {
    String capitalized = askWork.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + askWork.substring(1)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It worked! -- " + capitalized);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to trim the input before you start manipulating its contents:

```
String askWork = input.nextLine().trim();

String workplace = askWork.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + askWork.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without substrings:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String askWork = input.nextLine().trim();

    while (askWork.isEmpty())
        askWork = input.nextLine().trim();

    char[] workChars = askWork.toCharArray();
    workChars[0] = workChars[0].toUpperCase();

    String workplace = String.valueOf(workChars);

    // Work with workplace

    input.close();
}
```